# Export html tables to Excel using (or not) javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel

I made an statistics application which only permits actually to display various informations, using angular. Now i want to improve it.

On a page i have 3 big html tables containing the statistics and i'd like to let the users download them to use them on excel.

I've seen many ways to do it only in javascript but it's a bit too basic and for example, we can ony create one sheet by excel file. I used for a previous project a php Class to create my excel files which was really better.

Can you advise me about a way to create a more complex excel file, on my angular application, by calling maybe an external script or something?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There are a plenty of solutions for your problem. All depends of your application, backend capabilities, frameworks used and so on... 
A solution could be to create a webservice that uses the [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) apis.